# Regex check if backslash before every symbols using python

Tags: python, regex

I met some problems when I'd like to check if the input regex if correct or not.

I'd like to check is there one backslash before every symbol, but I don't know how to implement using Python.

For example:

- `number: 123456789`. (return `False`)
- `phone\:111111` (return `True`)

I try to use `(?!)` and `(?=)` in Python, but it doesn't work.

Update:

I'd like to match the following string:

`\~`, `\!`, `\@`, `\$`, `\%`, `\^`, `\&`, `\*`, `\(`, `\)`, `\{`, `\}`, `\[`, `\]`, `\:`, `\;`, `\"`, `\'`,  `\>`, `\<`, `\?`

Thank you very much.

Comment: `:` doesn't require any escaping in regex

Comment: What do you mean by symbols?

Comment: Did you mean to say *before every non-word symbol*? `r"(?:(?<=\\\\)|(?<!\\))[^\w\\]"`?

Comment: What would be the output if the input is `foo` ?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the entire string is composed of single characters or pairs of backslash+symbol:

```
import re
def has_backslash_before_every_symbol(s):
    return re.match(r"^(\\[~!@$%^&*(){}\[\]:;"'><?]|[^~!@$%^&*(){}\[\]:;"'><?])*$", s) is not None
```

Python regex reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
if re.seach(r"\\\W", "phone\:111111") is not None:
      print("OK")
```

Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines a bit, it sounds like you are trying to pass a string to a regex and you want to make sure it has no special characters in it that are unescaped.

Python's `re` module has an inbuilt [`re.escape()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) function for this.

**Example:**

```
>>> import re
>>> print(re.escape("phone:111111"))
"phone\\:111111"
```